# Select specific database from multiple database with odbcConnect in R

Tags: r, hive, rodbc

I’m very fresh with database and R. At the moment, I would like to connect R with database(Hive) and use R as the tool to query data from source.

The problem is that we have multiple databases, but I just wanna connect the specific database to work around. How to do that in R? For now, i’m using USE statement to select specific database but it is not working.

My script is

```
Library(“DBI”)
Library(“RODBC”)

Conn<- odbcConnect(dsn=“Mydsn”)
Query<- “USE MY_SPECIFIC_DATABASE
         SELECT*FROM MY_TABLE”
Res<-sqlQuery(Conn, Query)
```

I know we can select by [database].[table]. But I really appreciated if you have another way to solve this problem.

Also I cannot edit info in DSN cause no permission.

Please give me some advises to deal with this issue. Thank you

Comment: I do not know does  ODBC support USE or not but after `USE MY_SPECIFIC_DATABASE` should be semicolon because it is separate statement, though it may not be supported by ODBC driiver. It is possible to specify database in ODBC DSN